# How to upload to Firebase Storage with a submit button

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm new to Firebase and I got the code from the [Firebase repo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/storage/index.html) that listens to the HTML file input box and when you choose a file, it uploads automatically:

```
 window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

I just wanted to make it upload only when I click 'submit'. I made a button with `id="submit"` and changed the event listener:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', handleFileSelect, false);
```

But I'm getting an error that `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.
That comes from the handleFileSelect function. How can I fix it?

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var file = evt.target.files[0];

    var metadata = {
      'contentType': file.type
    };

    storageRef.child(file.name).put(file, metadata).then(function(snapshot) {
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: The event is not the file input's change event any longer, so you need to replace `evt.target` with `document.getElementById('file')`

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, thanks.